# Figo staging of ovarian cancer

Tags: obstetrics, metastatic-cancer

What stage would it be if the PELVIC lymph nodes are involved in case of ovarian cancer?
Will it be stage 2 as it is pelvic organ or will it be stage 3 as it will be retroperitoneal?

Comment: Hi user133880, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Where do you see being retroperitoneal as being a stage 3 criteria? That's the kind of thing we expect to see from prior research. Who says that's a criteria?

Comment: According to the Figo staging 2014.this is being taught to us that retroperitoneal lymph nodes involvement is 3a stage

Comment: What I'm asking you to do is [edit] your question and add a link to a source stating that retroperitoneal lymph node involvement meets 3a criteria. Better yet would be a a link and a brief quote from the source. Everything one needs to understand your question needs to be in the question itself, not in comments. Comments are subject to deletion at any time.